# Next.js: How can I use getStaticProps/getStaticPaths for sites with multiple domains/hostnames?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

I’m building a site with the structure `https://[sub.domain.ext]/[language]/articles/[slug]`, however it will have different content on different domains (different hostnames).

A typical use case of this would be different subdomains for different language translations of the same content: en.mysite.com, fr.mysite.com, etc.

I don’t want to resort to server-side rendering using `getServerSideProps` (slower performance and unnecessary if content rarely changes). Can I somehow use `getStaticProps`/`getStaticPaths` for static site generation?

Here’s my current implementation with `siteId = 1` hardcoded:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

import Page from 'components/page/Page'
import Error from 'components/page/Error'
import ArticleList from 'components/articles/ArticleList'

const { runDatabaseFunction } = require('lib/database')
const { getArticlesForSiteAndLanguage } = require('lib/data/articles')

function ArticleListPage ({ site, articles, error }) {
  const { asPath } = useRouter()
  const title = 'News'
  return (
    <Page
      title={title}
      site={site}
      path={asPath}
    >
      <h1>{title}</h1>

      {error && <Error error={error} />}

      <ArticleList
        articles={articles}
      />
    </Page>
  )
}
export default ArticleListPage

export async function getStaticProps ({ params: { siteId = 1, languageCode = 'en' } }) {
  return {
    revalidate: 10,
    props: await runDatabaseFunction(async (pool) => getArticlesForSiteAndLanguage(pool, { siteId, languageCode }))
  }
}

export async function getStaticPaths () {
  return {
    paths: [
      { params: { languageCode: 'en' } } //  '[siteId]' is not part of folder structure
    ],
    fallback: true
  }
}
```

### Update

See also:

- https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/17060
- https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/12848

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of approaches:

### 1. Using Next.js locale system

Here’s an example of hosting **multiple domains on the same Next.js site** (while maintaining **multiple languages** and static site generation/SSG), using Next.js’ i18n system:

- Demo: https://multi-domain-locale1.vercel.app/
- Source: https://github.com/tomsoderlund/nextjs-multi-domain-locale

The concept:

- Next.js’ i18n `locale` is used to determine the *site*.
- Selecting a *language* is instead handled via a `pseudoLocale` prop (pages in a `/[pseudoLocale]` folder).
- A *redirect* from `/` to `/en`.

### 2. Using rewrites in Next.js 10.2

See [this conversation](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/12848#discussioncomment-680225) and [this code repository](https://github.com/acorcutt/next-multi-host).